# Why new keyword considered as high coupling in Java?

Tags: java, decoupling

I am working on Java for some time. I saw there are too many talks about decoupling the objects. I see they say "new" keyword is considered as symbol of high coupling. I did not get any answer till now why it is. can anyone explain me?

Comment: Yes, where they rather would like to see injection. But there are quite many cases, perhaps the majority of it, where you would't inject but use `new` anyway, like in `new List<String>` e.g. `new BigDecimal(...)` ... who would inject such stuff?

Comment: the use of the new word will have to go somewhere. So you have to decide when it is beneficial to remove this coupling. There are a number of libraries that provide this capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `new` creates an instance of a specific class.  So whenever you use `new` you are creating coupling between the class being created and the code that creates it.  Example:

```
   List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

creates an instance of `ArrayList`, which is a problem if you don't *need* to hard-wire the code to use that specific implementation of the `List` API.

Note that Java `new` doesn't allow you to make the class name a parameter.  Not even with generic type parameters.

The alternative is to use a factory function or object, or use dependency injection to decouple the code that needs the instance of a class from the procedure that creates it.  (Or pass around `Class` objects as parameters and use reflection to create instances.)